# card shadow is not working when use by Recyclerview with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android

When CardView is using in Recyclerview item as GridLayoutManager the cardview shadow is not working. When elevation set more than the 2dp it is not working

Comment: Add app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" to your Card

Answer (score 0):

May be it is working but if you have multiple views with small margins ,you cannot observe the change .Try changing the margins size .